# Android Room Entity with FTS4 does not create table with 'rowid' column

Tags: android, android-room

So I have ran into this peculiar case.

My entity class looks like this:

```
@Entity(tableName = "drafts")
@Fts4
@Data
public class DraftEntity {

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "rowid") // Fts requirement
    public int draftId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "main_content")
    private String mainContent;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "plain_text_content")
    private String plainTextContent;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "cover_img_url")
    private String coverImgUrl;

    ...
}
```

Its not **autoincrement** because I want to manage the ID since it'll sync with the server as well.
In the database inspector, I see the column 'rowid' isn't present only!.

[image]

How i the world am I supposed to retrieve the row? I don't know what I am missing here. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**rowid** is a hidden column it always exists unless you specify WITHOUT ROWID when defining the table. You can use **rowid** specifically.

e.g. :-

```
@Query("SELECT rowid,* FROM drafts WHERE drafts.rowid = :id")
DraftEntity getDraftById(long id);
```

## Demo/Test

Using the following in an Activity :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DraftDatabase draftDatabase;
    DraftEntityDao draftEntityDao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        draftDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(this,DraftDatabase.class,"draftdb")
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();
        draftEntityDao = draftDatabase.draftEntityDao();
        DraftEntity draft = new DraftEntity();
        draft.setTitle("Draft1");
        draft.setPlainTextContent("blah");
        draft.setMainContent("blah blah blah");
        draft.setCoverImgUrl("here");
        long thisdraft =draftEntityDao.insert(draft);
        DraftEntity addedDraft = draftEntityDao.getDraftById(thisdraft);
        logDraftInfo(addedDraft);

    }

    private void logDraftInfo(DraftEntity d) {
        Log.d("DRAFTINTO",
                "Draft Title is " + d.getTitle() +
                        "\n\tPlain text is " + d.getPlainTextContent() +
                        "\n\tMain text is " + d.getMainContent() +
                        "\n\tURL is " + d.getCoverImgUrl() +
                        "\n\tRowid aka DraftID is " + String.valueOf(d.getDraftId())

        );
    }
}
```

Results in :-

```
2019-12-21 09:22:21.665 7632-7632/? D/DRAFTINTO: Draft Title is Draft1
        Plain text is blah
        Main text is blah blah blah
        URL is here
        Rowid aka DraftID is 1
```